# Problem with AWS Amplify + NextJS + Streaming API response

Tags: amazon-web-services, next.js, aws-amplify, next.js13

I am running NextJS on AWS Amplify. I have an API call that takes a while so I am streaming it instead. Works great on local but streaming doesn't work when push to AWS Amplify and is exceeding the 30 secs timeout.

What can I do please?

Frontend:

```
try {
      setLoading(true);
      setAnswer('');
      const res = await fetch(`/api/test?question=${question}`);
      if (res.ok) {
        // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ReadableStream/getReader
        const reader = res?.body?.getReader();
    
        const processStream = async () => {
          while(true) {
            const {done, value} = await reader?.read() || {};

            if (!value) {
              setLoading(false);
              break;
            }

            if(done) {
              setLoading(false);
              break;
            }

            let chunk = new TextDecoder('utf-8').decode(value)

            chunk = chunk.replace(/^data: /, '');

            setAnswer((prev) => prev + chunk);
          }
        }
    
        processStream().catch(err => console.log('--stream error--', err))
  
      } else {
        setAnswer("Sorry, there was an error fetching your answer. Please try again later.");
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error fetching answer:", error);
      setAnswer("Sorry, there was an error fetching your answer. Please try again later.");
    }
```

Thank you